# Tracking brackets in a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am having the following string and want to track the closing bracket of `ROUND(` `)` in my string.

`"=ROUND(IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF($BY18=3;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;ROUND(CA18*CB18;$M$10)/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12;$M$11)";`

```
public class RoundParser {

    public static String parseRound(String text) {

        text = text.toUpperCase();

        String result;

        char[] ch = text.toCharArray();
        int count = -1;
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            temp = temp + ch[i];

            System.out.println(count);

            if ("ROUND(".equals(temp)) {
                count++;
            }
            if ("(".equals(temp)) {
                count++;
            }
            if (")".equals(temp) && count > 0) {
                count--;
            }
            if (")".equals(temp) && count == 0) {
                ch[i] = '#';
            }
            if (!"ROUND(".startsWith(temp) || temp.length() > 5) {
                temp = "";
            }
        }

        text = String.valueOf(ch);

        result = text;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "=ROUND(IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF($BY18=3;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;ROUND(CA18*CB18;$M$10)/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12;$M$11)";

        System.out.println(parseRound(text));
    }

}
```

However, using my parser at the moment I am getting:

`=ROUND(IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF($BY18=3;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;ROUND(CA18*CB18;$M$10)/$M$9;CA18*CB18))#/$M$12;$M$11#`

The output I want to get is:

`=ROUND(IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF($BY18=3;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;ROUND(CA18*CB18;$M$10#/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12;$M$11#`

As you can see the not the right ) are replaced, as `;$M$11)";` and `;$M$10)`. I really appreciate if you have any idea how to repalce these two cases.

Comment: If you start in the reverse way, the first ")" you encounter will be the last ")"

Comment: you have to implement a single for loop and only check for the ')' and store its position simultaneously, that way you can get the position of the last ')'.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thx for your answer! Pls provide an example!

Comment: @aradhna Thx but how to distinguish if the `)` is the closing bracket of the `ROUND(`?

Comment: be more specific as to what you want to do... to track the last ')' or to track the closing bracket for ROUND?

Comment: @Kare - Frankly speaking.. I am not getting your question entirely.. What is it that you want to do?. Give sample input and output..

Comment: `temp.endsWith("ROUND(")` instead of `"ROUND(".equals(temp)` and such.

Comment: Throw it all away and start again with the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm or a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thx for your reply! I edited my answer, would appreciate your reply!

Comment: @EJP Any recommendations how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 approaches to this

1) if the number of opening and closing brackets are always going to be equal, then you can just track the last closing bracket by using a for loop.

2) if you are not sure about opening and closing brackets to be equal, then you can so the following-->

```
public class RoundParser {

    public static String parseRound(String text) {

        text = text.toUpperCase();

        String result;

        char[] ch = text.toCharArray();

     int count=0,pos=0;
        int c[10];
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){

        if(ch[i].equals("(")){
        count++;  
         if(ch[i-1].equals("D")){
              c[pos]=count;   //will store the count value at every opening round
                  pos++;
              }
        }

        if(ch[i].equals(")")){
        count--;
         for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
             if(c[j]==count)   //if the closing of round had been encountered
                   ch[i]="#";   
         }
       }

        }


        text = String.valueOf(ch);

        result = text;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "=ROUND(IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF($BY18=3;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;ROUND(CA18*CB18;$M$10)/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12;$M$11)";

        System.out.println(parseRound(text));
    }

}
```

there you go.

i think this should work.

hope this helps.

Comment: +1.ya.. this should work (if i understood the OP's problem correctly..)

Comment: @aradhna Please put this into a working function and I will accept your answer!

Comment: @Kare what do you want me to do?

Comment: @aradhna I would appreciate it if you could put it into a working function, so that I can accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot an `else`:

```
else if (")".equals(temp) && count == 0) {
```

That will decrement `count` and if then `count==0`, it will decrement twice.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be done recursively.

First, you use method `.indexOf("ROUND(")` to detect the first occurrence of round().

Then, we need to determine which is the end ')' of this round(). A simple algo will be enough :

```
int start = text.indexOf("ROUND(") + "ROUND(".length();

int count = 1;
int end = -1;
for(int i = start; i < text.length; i++){ 
    if(text.charAt(i) == '('){
       count++;
    }else if(text.charAt(i) == ')'){
       count--;
    }
    if(count == 0){
       end = i;
       break;
    }
}
```

After you detect the start and end of the outer `round()`, you can use `text.substring(start, end)` to remove the outer round(), and continue the above function recursively, until you find all `round()`

Answer (score 1):

For recognition of multiple `ROUND(X)`, I suggest

```
TreeMap<Integer,Pair<Integer,Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();

int count = 0;
```

Where we store `<start_index, <init_count, end_index>>`

```
if ("ROUND(".equals(temp))
{
    map.put(i, new Pair<Integer,Integer>(count, -1));
    count++;
}

if ("(".equals(temp)) count++;

if (")".equals(temp))
{
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        count = 0;
        // Error: extra closing bracket
    }
    else
    {
        count--;
    }

    int max_i = -1;

    for (Integer index : map.keySet())
    {
        if (index > max_i
          && map.get(index).second() == -1
          && map.get(index).first() == count)
        {
            max_i = index;
        }
    }

    if (max_i > -1) map.get(max_i).setSecond(i);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, without putting it into a method its hard for me to try it out. I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Kare it's a pseudo-code, you need to integrate the idea, my idea is to use a map of `start index`es and look for a `closing bracket` that match the `init count` of that call .. note also that you need to write a class `Pair`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm.. 
If you are not sure that the last ")" would be the one you are looking for.
Start from index 0 of the String, for each "(" you encounter, increment the count, and for each ")" decrement the count, replace the ")" with "#".