# Java - Checking opening/closing parens in String

Tags: java, string, brackets

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a `String` is formatted correctly with parens: `(` and `)`.  There should be the same number of `(` as `)`.  Also, the parens should be formatted correctly so that a `(` and `)` form a pair.  Other characters may appear in the `String`.

Examples:

```
"()()()()()()()"   // Valid
"((a)(b)((cd)e))"  // Valid
"((d()mk()))()"    // Valid
"((d()mk())))("    // Invalid, the last two parens don't form a pair.
")()"              // Invalid, not equal number of paren types
```

So, I figured the first step is to check if there are the same number of `(` as `)` in the `String` (I found this page to help with that [Brackets in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362335/tracking-brackets-in-a-string),)).

**I don't know how to approach the part to check if the `String` is formatted correctly.**

Could you guys give me a hint?

EDIT:

My solution is:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class BracketProblem {

    public boolean checkBrackets(String str) {
        Stack st = new Stack();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char x = str.charAt(i);
            if (x == '(')
                st.push(x);

            if (!st.empty()){
                if (x == ')') 
                    st.pop();
            }
        }

        if(!st.empty()) 
            return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = args[0];       
        BracketProblem bp = new BracketProblem();
        System.out.println(bp.checkBrackets(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a stack - when you read a `(` add it onto the stack, when you read a `)` pop a `(` off of the stack.  If you don't get any errors and have an empty stack at the end it's good.

Comment: @Andrew_CS You may want to add that as an answer...

Comment: If you are taking an abstract data types class (or not) I would do as Andrew suggests and use a stack. Learn a little about them, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type). Java Stack: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: Question is edited to be more clear on what the OP wants - shouldn't be on hold anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a stack - Read over the `char` in the `String`.  Push `(` as you read them.  Pop `(` as you read `)`.

Things to watch out for:

- If you read an `)` and there is not a `(` on top of the stack then that's an error.
- If you get to the end of the `String` and the stack isn't empty then that's an error.
- If you get to the end of the `String` and the stack is empty then it's a valid `String`.

Here is a link that explains the [Stack Concept](http://www.c4learn.com/data-structure/stack-concept-overview-definition/).

*Note:* For your purposes you can ignore the other `char` in the `String`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew_CS, I will try this solution now!

Comment: @user3831988 I hope this approach works for you - Stack is a data structure that you should get familiar with regardless since it helps with many other problems that you'll face in the future. Don't forget to accept an answer if your original question has been answered. Happy programming!

Comment: Hi  Andrew_CS, thank you very much for your help, I solved the problem with the stack! Also, thanks for making my problem clear!

Comment: no need to use additional memory

Comment: @SargeBorsch Why the downvote? If your comment about memory is referring to the use of a stack - a stack is a good choice since the functionality can easily be extended if other chars are required such as { } [ ].  Also, it's good practice for the OP to learn about the data structure.

Comment: @Andrew_CS Sarge is correct, however, the OP did not mention any constraints so I do think that this is a decent way of going about things and thus no downvote from me.

Answer (score 4):

Grab a piece of paper, write down your string on it with a pencil (pen will do), and then do the checking yourself, while keeping track of your progress on the paper.

Now try to formulate what you're doing in Java.

**Update:** Sorry if this sounds rude and unhelpful at first but the ability to work things out for yourself is **far** more important than any algorithm.

Comment: Hi biziclop,I don't think your reply is rude, but I was doing the same thing you wrote: I tried to solve the problem on paper first, I just got stuck...

Answer (score 2):

Make a counter variable; increment it upon seeing `(` and decrement it upon seeing `)`. If your counter variable is not 0 at the end, you have an uneven number of parentheses.

**However**, as [ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464386/ajb) suggested in the comments, make sure that the counter variable never goes negative, as this would mean a case such as `)(` (which is an even number of parentheses, but technically not matching).

Comment: Also make sure the counter never goes negative.  You want to be able to catch `")("`.